# Shortest path of two vertices in spanning tree with edges all the same distance

Tags: graph, shortest-path, vertex, spanning-tree

I have a spanning tree of a graph, starting from a vertex v. All the edges are the same distance (Let's say 1).

How can I work out what the shortest path from v to another vertex u?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the shortest path from vertex `v` to any vertex `u` given just a spanning tree.
Consider the following graph where the cost of all edges equals to `1`:

```
               v
              / \
             /   \
            /     \
           u-------w
```

Clearly the shortest path between `v` and `u` is `1`.

However, consider the following spanning tree of the above graph:

```
                   v
                    \
                     \
                      \
               u-------w
```

If we are not given the graph, we cannot know that there is an edge between `v` and `u`. So, we can only say that there is a path from `v` to `u` through `w` of length `2`.